# Kaobook- does not compile

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

Actually, I am a super beginner user of latex and to write my thesis I decided to use kaobook template. I tried to compile it on my laptop but it makes error "LaTeX Error: File `newpxtext.sty' not found."

Could you please help me?

PS: I have tried to compile it on Overleaf and it compiles completely.

Comment: if you are using texlive then `tlmgr install newpx`  should install the needed package and fonts. Miktex usually installs things automatically when needed but you can force it to install if that fails (sorry I can't help with the details with miktex) You didn't say which tex system you are using

Comment: Beginner + large project + template = big troubles. I will start with a standard book-like class and go step by step, adding code to change the defaults  only if you know what you are doing.  In other words:  you must control the code. Don't let the code control you.

Comment: I have tried this command but it did not work. I am using TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian and my os is ubuntu 19.

Comment: "It did not work" did not help. Things  fail by a lot of reasons, we are not fortune-tellers with a crystal ball to see what are you doing.  What is the error message of tlmgr? Are you using the vanilla TeXLive 2019 (now frozen)? It is a global install or only for one user? Or you are using the Texlive of the Ubuntu packages?  What tell you `locate newpxtext.sty`?

Comment: BTW, if you are using  .deb packages, try  `sudo apt texlive-fonts-extra`

Comment: Actually, I installed a new version of texlive (2020) and that problem has been solved but currently it complaints "! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `smallerops' for package `txfonts'"